# Include table as a subfigure

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats

Is it possible to include "table code" as a sub-figure (instead of an image) using the package `subfig`? If so, how?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can include any content (table, text, figure, ...) within a `figure` or `table` environment. That is, there is no restriction to only have figures within a `figure` environment, nor to only have a `tabular` within a `table` environment. The same goes for `\subfloat` from the `\subfig` package. The respective environments just maintain different counters and they end up in different "List of ..."s - administrative differences of sorts.

Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\mytab}{% Just for this example
  \begin{tabular}{lcr}
    \toprule
    One & Two & Three \\
    \midrule
    $x$ & $y$ & $z$ \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\mytab}%
  \qquad
  \subfloat[][]{\mytab}
  \caption{Here are some tables in a \texttt{figure} environment.}%
  \label{fig:table}%
\end{figure}

\begin{table}%
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\mytab}%
  \qquad
  \subfloat[][]{\mytab}
  \caption{Here are some tables in a \texttt{table} environment.}%
  \label{tbl:table}%
\end{table}

\end{document}​
```

Comment: Is caption label the only difference between `figure` and `table` ? I really don't know this.

Comment: Which `%` is/are really necessary in your code above?

Comment: @DamienWalters: As mentioned, the caption label displays differently, the environments maintain different counters and end up in different "List of..."s, but apart from that, they're the same things - an environment that can float. In the above code, perhaps only `%` following `\subfloat` seems necessary (not exactly sure). I took the example from the [`subfig` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Use package \usepackage{subfig}, and the latex code is

```
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\subfloat[Caption for subtable 1]{%
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
\hline
Regressor Model & Train & Test \\
\hline

\end{tabular}}
\quad % Adjust the spacing between subtables if needed
\subfloat[Caption for subtable 2]{%
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
\hline
Regressor Model & Train & Test \\
\hline
% Add your table content here
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Overall table caption}
\label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}
```