# Input a table into a subfigure, get the error "Not in outer par mode"

Tags: tables, floats

My question is it possible to put a table in the place of a figure when using subfigures? 
I have tried this example:
[Include table as a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47311/include-table-as-a-subfigure)

but I get the following error: **Not in outer par mode**

I am using the subcaption package. Which is different. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\begin{center}
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Expected size of adapter sequences}
        \begin{tabular}{rr}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Vis} & \textbf{Expected size of adapter} \\
        \midrule
        V-R-is  & 8 \\
        V-R-8co-is & 1 \\
        V-R-12co-my & 1 \\
        V-R-G7co-s & 1 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{targ_recomb.eps}
            \caption{PCR produc}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{targ_recomb2.eps}
            \caption{1173 reverse primer.}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{PC results}
    \label{fig:PCRresult}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

O and btw the **\centering** doesn't seem to work hence the **\begin{center}**

Is this possible using the **\usepackage{subcaption}**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the `[H]` specifier in general, but especially in this case where the object you want to typeset is quite big: there's no hope it will fit “here”.

You can profit from `caption` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering

\begingroup % make the next setting local
\captionsetup{type=table} % here we want to caption a table

\caption{Expected size of adapter sequences}
\label{tab:addlabel}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\toprule
\textbf{Vis} & \textbf{Expected size of adapter} \\
\midrule
V-R-is  & 8 \\
V-R-8co-is & 1 \\
V-R-12co-my & 1 \\
V-R-G7co-s & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\bigskip % some vertical space

\begin{subfigure}{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{targ_recomb.eps}
  \caption{PCR produc}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.7\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.40]{targ_recomb2.eps}
  \caption{1173 reverse primer.}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{PC results}
\label{fig:PCRresult}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd probably use `\begin{tabular}{lc}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{lr}` because of the wide header.