# An alternative way to align figure and table in \subfloat

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats, mactex

So I realise this has been asked/alluded to a couple of times previously as in:

[Figure and table side-by-side in subfloats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28666/figure-and-table-side-by-side-in-subfloats)

[Table and Figure side-by-side with Table caption above, Figure caption below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101980/table-and-figure-side-by-side-with-table-caption-above-figure-caption-below?lq=1)

Where ultimately it seems some issues may arise due to bad captioning or use of `hyperref`, though exactly why still isn't overly clear to me. Nevertheless, I'm not using `hyperref` and am trying to achieve 4 (or maybe even greater) panel of images, with an inset table.

I was following the approach of [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47311/include-table-as-a-subfigure), by defining my table as a command object, but its still not playing ball.

I currently have this:

[image: Document as it currently stands]

and would like all 4 (technically 5 since the graph legend is an image I've tacked in) to sit in panels 2 below 2 - effectively, the table needs to come up a couple of centimetres. The most promising avenue of approach I think was probably the `\raisebox` as mentioned in one of the answers, but either it won't work or I'm muddling the syntax. It was throwing me some TeX capacity exceeded error.

I'll try to give a MWE, but as I'm not really sure where my error is coming from, I don't know entirely what will be relevant and not. Oh I should probably point out that I'm using the Royal Society of Chemistry's template too (no choice!).

```
\documentclass[8.5pt, oneside, twocolumn]{article}
    \oddsidemargin -1.2cm
    \evensidemargin -1.2cm
    \textwidth 18cm
    \headheight 1.0in
    \topmargin -3.5cm
    \textheight 22cm
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % Included for the sake of completeness since hyperref had caused similar problems in the other threads. Doubt this is the source of the issue though.
\usepackage[format=plain,
        justification=raggedright, 
        singlelinecheck=false, 
        font=small,labelfont=bf,
        labelsep=space]{caption} % A 'default' caption to use unless specified otherwise by me

\begin{document}

% Defining my table object for calling to subfloat:

\newcommand{\slopetable}{
\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular*}{0.43\textwidth}{llll}
\hline    \\[-1.7ex]
Assay & \pbox{1.2cm}{Linear regression coefficient (3 s. f.)} & \pbox{1.2cm}{Normalised linear regression coefficient (3 s. f.)} & \pbox{1cm}{Activity (\%)}  \\
\\[-2ex]
\hline
\\[-1.5ex]
                WT MeOH PTC          & 0.308    & 1.00  & 100   \\
                WT Tunicamycin       & 0.374    & 1.21  &  121  \\
                F288W Tunicamycin    & 0.382    & 1.24  &  124  \\
\\[-1.5ex]  
                F288W E-peptide [37] & 0.402    & 1.30  & 130   \\
                F288W E-peptide [62] & 0.223    & 0.742 & 74.2  \\
                F288W E-peptide [83] & 0.820    & 2.66  & 266   \\
\\[-1.5ex]
                F288W RWGLW [166]    & 0.409    & 1.32  &  132  \\
                F288W RWGLW [416]    & 0.304    & 0.985 &  98.5 \\
                F288W RWGLW [624]    & 0.276    & 0.896 &  89.6 \\
\\[-1.5ex]
                F288W GW-Oct [83]   & 0.209  &  0.677   & 67.7  \\
                F288W GW-Oct [166]  & 0.0194 &  0.0630  & 6.30  \\
                F288W GW-Oct [416]  & 0.0510 & 0.165    & 16.5  \\
\\[-0.5ex]
\hline
\end{tabular*}
}

% Begin constructing multi-panel figure:


\begin{figure*}[t]
    \subfloat[{Dummy caption 1.}\label{rawdata}]{   
         \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,clip=true,trim=0 0 20 25]{Raw_data_plot_8x11}} 
    \subfloat[{Dummy caption 2.}\label{smoothdata}]{
         \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,clip=true,trim=0 0 20 25]{Smoothed_data_plot_8x11}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty} % Butchering duplicate graph to obtain an un-captioned image at the far right
\subfloat[]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.19\textwidth,clip=true, trim= 655 155 0 150 ]{Plot_for_legend}}

% Beginning of panel causing issues
\subfloat[][]{\slopetable}
\subfloat[{}\label{LinearRegression}]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,clip=true, left, trim= 0 0 0 0]{Linear_regression_plot}}

\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified}
\caption{
Temp placeholder caption}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I hope that's enough to go on for now at least - any help would be great. I'd ideally like to avoid `bodging` it with minipages and so on if possible though.

**EDIT - Somewhat tweaked MWE that replicates the problem, left the original one there incase a solution is found that directly relates to that code.**

```
\documentclass[8.5pt, oneside, twocolumn]{article}
\oddsidemargin -1.2cm
\evensidemargin -1.2cm
\textwidth 18cm
\headheight 1.0in
\topmargin -3.5cm
\textheight 22cm
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url} % Included for the sake of completeness since hyperref had caused similar problems in the other threads. Doubt this is the source of the issue though.
\usepackage[format=plain,
    justification=raggedright, 
    singlelinecheck=false, 
    font=small,labelfont=bf,
    labelsep=space]{caption} % A 'default' caption to use unless specified otherwise by me

\begin{document}

% Defining my table object for calling to subfloat:

\newcommand{\slopetable}{
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular*}[b]{0.43\textwidth}{llll}
\hline    \\[-1.7ex]
Assay & \pbox{1.2cm}{Linear regression coefficient (3 s. f.)} & \pbox{1.2cm}{Normalised linear regression coefficient (3 s. f.)} & \pbox{1cm}{Activity (\%)}  \\
\\[-2ex]
\hline
\\[-1.5ex]
            WT MeOH PTC          & 0.308    & 1.00  & 100   \\
            WT Tunicamycin       & 0.374    & 1.21  &  121  \\
            F288W Tunicamycin    & 0.382    & 1.24  &  124  \\
\\[-1.5ex]  
            F288W E-peptide [37] & 0.402    & 1.30  & 130   \\
            F288W E-peptide [62] & 0.223    & 0.742 & 74.2  \\
            F288W E-peptide [83] & 0.820    & 2.66  & 266   \\
\\[-1.5ex]
            F288W RWGLW [166]    & 0.409    & 1.32  &  132  \\
            F288W RWGLW [416]    & 0.304    & 0.985 &  98.5 \\
            F288W RWGLW [624]    & 0.276    & 0.896 &  89.6 \\
\\[-1.5ex]
            F288W GW-Oct [83]   & 0.209  &  0.677   & 67.7  \\
            F288W GW-Oct [166]  & 0.0194 &  0.0630  & 6.30  \\
            F288W GW-Oct [416]  & 0.0510 & 0.165    & 16.5  \\
\\[-0.5ex]
\hline
\end{tabular*}
}

% Begin constructing multi-panel figure:


\begin{figure*}[t]
\subfloat[{Dummy caption 1.}\label{rawdata}]{   
     \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,clip=true,trim=0 0 20 25]{Raw_data_plot_8x11}} 
\subfloat[{Dummy caption 2.}\label{smoothdata}]{
     \includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth,clip=true,trim=0 0 20 25]{Smoothed_data_plot_8x11}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty} 
\subfloat[]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth,clip=true, trim= 655 155 0 150 ]{Plot_for_legend}}

% Beginning of panel causing issues
\subfloat[][]{\slopetable}
\subfloat[{}\label{LinearRegression}]{%
\includegraphics[height=5cm, draft]{Linear_regression_plot}}


\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Dodgy table alignment by MWE2]

Comment: your tabular has the default `[c]` position so its baseline goes through its centre, which is why the centre of the table is aligned with the base of the image you want `\begin{tabular}[b]`

Comment: I had originally thought this too, but upon trying it, I get a 'missing number treated as zero' error in (according to TeX at least) the `\subfloat[][]` line.

Comment: most likely you did something wrong then:-) please fix your example so it is a complete document so that people can see the issue. use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` so we don't need the images and add `\end[document}`

Comment: Oh yeah missed that, will append now.

Comment: the example generates `! Package keyval Error: left undefined.`

Comment: So I see =/   not sure whats causing that either, but a tweaked MWE that I'll add as an edit above still produces the same kind of issue I'm dealing with.

Comment: you have an undefined key `left` on `\includegraphics` if I delete that I get no error and the table moves as expected with `\begin{tabular*}{0.43\textwidth}[b]{llll}` as defn of slopetable

Comment: Looks as though thats done it. Seems as though it was because I had `[b]` as `\begin{tabular*}[b]{0.43\textwidth}{llll}` rather than before the `llll` based on your first comment. How very silly... thanks for the help, just needed a spare set of eyes I think! Would you formalise your comments as an answer that I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tabular has the default `[c]` position so its baseline goes through its centre, which is why the centre of the table is aligned with the base of the image you want:
 `\begin{tabular}[b]` or more exactly as you are using `tabular*` :

```
 \begin{tabular*}[b]{0.43\textwidth}{llll}
```

which will line the baseline of the bottom row (or `\hline` in this case) of the tabular with the base of the image.