# It is possible to put a table as part of a figure with separate labels and captions?

Tags: captions, labels, subcaption

Is it possible to put a graph and a table together in one figure?

```
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{Fit3Dir_30min/ModelSelectionGraphs/Histogram_smad7_reproduced_AICc}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        Model Selection Criteria & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3\\
        \hline
        RSS  & 614.037  & 615.003 & 698.592\\
        AICc & 234.751  & 234.996 & 254.877\\
        BIC  & 264.25   & 264.495 & 284.376\\

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Distribution of corrected Akaike information criteria (AICc) per model}
    \label{fig:model_selection}
\end{figure}
```

This code produces :
[image]

which is only half way there. I would like to be able to add a separate caption and label to both the table and graph since they are separate things but still belong in one figure.

I have tried wrapping the table and graph parts of the figure in `subfigure` environment but it did not work and I have seen a few other posts such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47311/include-table-as-a-subfigure) which also has not solved my problem.

I'm looking for the simplest solution preferably using the subcaption package since this is what I'm using for the rest of my figures.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think a minipage with a figure and table inside is the way to go, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Cool. I'll have a google

Comment: Would you like them put side by side or one below the other? In other word, horizontal or vertical aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place the table below the picture, you can use the `subfig` package (as in the link you posted), like this

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[][]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image}
    }%
    \vfill
    \subfloat[][]{%
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        Model Selection Criteria & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3\\
        \hline
        RSS  & 614.037  & 615.003 & 698.592\\
        AICc & 234.751  & 234.996 & 254.877\\
        BIC  & 264.25   & 264.495 & 284.376\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{Distribution of corrected Akaike information criteria (AICc) per model}
    \label{fig:model_selection}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fit3Dir_30min/ModelSelectionGraphs/Histogram_smad7_reproduced_AICc}
\caption{Distribution of corrected Akaike information criteria (AICc) per model}
\label{fig:model_selection}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.57\linewidth}
\captionof{table}{A tabular caption}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
        Model Selection Criteria & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3\\\hline
        RSS  & 614.037  & 615.003 & 698.592\\
        AICc & 234.751  & 234.996 & 254.877\\
        BIC  & 264.25   & 264.495 & 284.376\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Herbert, thanks for the post. Would you happen to know how to get the table below the figure, rather than side by side?

Comment: Actually, I've figured out I can replace `\hfill` with `\vfill`. However there is one last problem - I need the Figure 1 part to be part `A` of the figure the table to be part `B`. Then Id like one overall caption for the whole figure at the bottom. Thanks again.

Comment: then you do not need minipages and let only one empty line between image and tabular. That's all