# How can I put a figure beside a table with a single caption for both figure and table?

Tags: tables, floats

I have a table below and I would like to insert a figure to its right. Both table and figure will use a single caption. Below is my code for the table.

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline%\noalign{\smallskip}
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:50}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:70}$} \\
 &  & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Deterministic} \ & 2D ConvLSTM \cite{convlstm} & 0.712 & 23.58 & 0.639 & 22.85 & 0.551 & 20.13 \\
& PredRNN++ \cite{wang-predrnn} & 0.865 & 28.47 & 0.741 & 25.21 & 0.702 & 23.51 \\ 
& E3D-LSTM \cite{wang-e3d} & \textbf{0.879} & \textbf{29.31} & 0.810 & 27.24 & 0.798 & 26.82 \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Stochastic} & Variational 2D ConvLSTM \cite{vrnn} & 0.787 & 25.76 & 0.733 & 24.83 & 0.672 & 23.13 \\
& Variational 3D ConvLSTM (Ours) & 0.866 & 28.31 & \textbf{0.852} & \textbf{27.89} & \textbf{0.846} & \textbf{27.66} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Results on the KTH action dataset when using 10 frames to predict 20 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$), 40 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:50}$), and 60 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:70}$) timesteps into the future. The metrics are computed frame-wise. Higher SSIM and PSNR scores indicate better results.}
\label{table:quantitativekth}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

I tried following the code here [Include table as a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47311/include-table-as-a-subfigure) but the figure always appears below.

```
\begin{table*}
\begin{center}
\subfloat[][]{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|cc|cc|cc|}
\hline%\noalign{\smallskip}
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:50}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:70}$} \\
 &  & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Deterministic} \ & 2D ConvLSTM \cite{convlstm} & 0.712 & 23.58 & 0.639 & 22.85 & 0.551 & 20.13 \\
& PredRNN++ \cite{wang-predrnn} & 0.865 & 28.47 & 0.741 & 25.21 & 0.702 & 23.51 \\ 
& E3D-LSTM \cite{wang-e3d} & \textbf{0.879} & \textbf{29.31} & 0.810 & 27.24 & 0.798 & 26.82 \\ 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Stochastic} & Variational 2D ConvLSTM \cite{vrnn} & 0.787 & 25.76 & 0.733 & 24.83 & 0.672 & 23.13 \\
& Variational 3D ConvLSTM (Ours) & 0.866 & 28.31 & \textbf{0.852} & \textbf{27.89} & \textbf{0.846} & \textbf{27.66} \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\quad
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{kth.png}}
\end{center}
\caption{Results on the KTH action dataset when using 10 frames to predict 20 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$), 40 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:50}$), and 60 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:70}$) timesteps into the future. The metrics are computed frame-wise. Higher SSIM and PSNR scores indicate better results.}
\label{table:quantitativekth}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the required packages. Regarding the second image: Did you get any error messages compiling your code? If so, which? (The `[][]` in your second screenshot makes me guess that you got an error message such as " Undefined control sequence. \subfloat" because you forgot to add the `subfig` package to your preamble.) Apart from that, your table and image are probably wider than the textwidth, hence they are placed below each other instead of side-by-side. This guess is however hard to confirm without a full MWE.

Comment: Your table is very wide as it is, so there's very little (no) room to place an image (chart) next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

- Your table is litle bit to wide, so in the following MWE i reduce used font size in table and size of `\tabcolsep`
- table and image are encapsulated in table
- for vertical centering of figure is used `valign=c` c option defined in `adjustbox` package (it also load `graphicx` package,

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lr @{}}
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{} |l|l|cc|cc|cc|@{}}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:50}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:70}$} \\
    &  & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Deterministic} \ & 2D ConvLSTM \cite{convlstm} & 0.712 & 23.58 & 0.639 & 22.85 & 0.551 & 20.13 \\
    & PredRNN++ \cite{wang-predrnn} & 0.865 & 28.47 & 0.741 & 25.21 & 0.702 & 23.51 \\
& E3D-LSTM \cite{wang-e3d} & \textbf{0.879} & \textbf{29.31} & 0.810 & 27.24 & 0.798 & 26.82 \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Stochastic} & Variational 2D ConvLSTM \cite{vrnn} & 0.787 & 25.76 & 0.733 & 24.83 & 0.672 & 23.13 \\
    & Variational 3D ConvLSTM (Ours) & 0.866 & 28.31 & \textbf{0.852} & \textbf{27.89} & \textbf{0.846} & \textbf{27.66}     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-duck}
    \end{tabular}

\caption{Results on the KTH action dataset when using 10 frames to predict 20 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$), 40 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:50}$), and 60 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:70}$) time steps into the future. The metrics are computed frame-wise. Higher SSIM and PSNR scores indicate better results.}
\label{table:quantitativekth}
        \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
If you like to have aligned table and image at their bottoms, than you just add option `[b]˙to insert4d table and at image remove option` valign=c`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lr @{}}
\small
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} |l|l|cc|cc|cc|@{}}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Type} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:50}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:70}$} \\
    &  & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR & SSIM & PSNR \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Deterministic} \ & 2D ConvLSTM \cite{convlstm} & 0.712 & 23.58 & 0.639 & 22.85 & 0.551 & 20.13 \\
    & PredRNN++ \cite{wang-predrnn} & 0.865 & 28.47 & 0.741 & 25.21 & 0.702 & 23.51 \\
& E3D-LSTM \cite{wang-e3d} & \textbf{0.879} & \textbf{29.31} & 0.810 & 27.24 & 0.798 & 26.82 \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Stochastic} & Variational 2D ConvLSTM \cite{vrnn} & 0.787 & 25.76 & 0.733 & 24.83 & 0.672 & 23.13 \\
    & Variational 3D ConvLSTM (Ours) & 0.866 & 28.31 & \textbf{0.852} & \textbf{27.89} & \textbf{0.846} & \textbf{27.66}     \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{tabular}

\caption{Results on the KTH action dataset when using 10 frames to predict 20 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:30}$), 40 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:50}$), and 60 ($\text{x}_{1:10} \rightarrow \hat{\text{x}}_{11:70}$) time steps into the future. The metrics are computed frame-wise. Higher SSIM and PSNR scores indicate better results.}
\label{table:quantitativekth}
        \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Latex is so difficult to understand. One last question, how would I vertically align my table to the bottom (or center) if the figure is taller than the table? e.g. valign=bottom or valign=c for tabular but I can't find a similar type of command for the table environment.

Comment: @Kong, you are welcome! Well, with some experiences all become clear and understandable :-)

Comment: @Kong, for bottom align of table and image remove `\valign=c` and at option `[b]` to inserted `tabular`: `\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} |l|l|cc|cc|cc|@{}}`.

Comment: Thank you very much!